# How do you use onPageLoad in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, firefox, tabs, onpageloadstring

I tried using

```
onPageLoad: function() {
    alert("hi");
}
```

but it won't work. I need it for a Firefox extension.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: specify in what context you use this, in html page? in extension?

Comment: Did you mean onPageLoad in the title?

Comment: sry yes i did mean onPageLoad and its in a firefox extension

Answer (score 14):

If you want to do this in vanilla javascript, just use the `window.onload` event handler.

```
window.onload = function() {
  alert('hi!');
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
var itsloading = window.onload;
```

or

```
<body onload="doSomething();"></body> 
//this calls your javascript function doSomething
```

**for your example**

```
<script language="javascript">

function sayhi() 
{
  alert("hi")
}
</script>

<body onload="sayhi();"></body>
```

**EDIT -**

For the extension in firefox [On page load](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Code_snippets/On_page_load) example

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you meant the onload-event:

You should use a javascript library like [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/ready#fn) to make it work in all browsers.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert("Hi!");
    });
</script>
```

If you really don't want to use a javascript library (Don't expect it to work well in all browsers.):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function sayHi() {
        alert("Hi!");
    }
</script>
<body onload="javascript:sayHi();">
...
```

Comment: The jQuery document ready event is not the same as the onload event. The ready event is fired when the DOM is parsed, the onload event is fired when all the items on the page (images etc.) have been loaded.

Comment: Also, the syntax for the <body onload=""> is the following: <body onload="sayHi()">. Adding javascript: will not work.

Answer (score 2):

```
       <script language="javascript">

    window.onload = onPageLoad();

    function onPageLoad() {
        alert('page loaded!');
        }
</script>
```

Comment: `window.onload = onPageLoad();` issues a call to `onPageLoad` immediately, which defeats the purpose.